# Need to know any sample URL to hit and check XCPD patient discovery request

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I need to hit the below provided SOAP request to any sample URL which can support patient discovery request (XCPD) protocol and respond to me back with the standard data (sample) against this request. I have attached the XML file which contains the request for XCPD patient discovery.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

XML Sample request: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n0NvrSEahACZXXiWkra48eERel9yHWUD/view?usp=share_link

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have been asissisted in the FHIR Community forum, so just adding the link here in case someone else has the same issue as you did: http://community.fhir.org/t/need-to-know-any-sample-url-to-hit-and-check-xcpd-patient-discovery-request/4176/2

PS: A list of available FHIR servers can be found at https://confluence.hl7.org/display/FHIR/Public+Test+Servers and is kept up to date to the extent possible.